# certification to get in order to save PHI for European businesses

Tags: privacy, hipaa, regulation, eu-data-protection

I work in a digital health company that will likely save personal Health information.

I am conflicting what certification I best get in order to best meet the needs of business partners from Europe.

Of course there are different requirements for different businesses.

I rather Not save American PHI in US servers and European PHI in European server.

My company is already Hippa complaint but that is good for American businesses (am I right?).

Currently all my data is stored on a self installed db (Mongodb) in google's cloud platform.

google is both Hippa complaint and [EU-US privacy shield certified](https://www.privacyshield.gov/participant?id=a2zt000000001L5AAI) 
What does that mean about my company?

I know that my company should implement these 3 mechanisms :

- Consent of patients to have their data stored
- Disclosure in case of breach
- Right to be Forgotten for any patients

Other than that, What certificate should we acquire to show our potential clients ?
should we encrypt the data ?
if yes, is it required to encrypt per partner or can we use one encryption key for the whole db ?

I've head of the GDPR framework but there is no organization to certify us for that, right ?